# CSS margin problem: I think/hope this is simple to fix?

Tags: html, css, margin

I recently finished a web version of an old text and I've been [getting help with my crappy novice-level CSS over at Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/css-novice-asking-for-help-with-web-version-of-old-text). The most recent version is [here](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~scmitche/clarkecollins2.html).

But here's the problem: somehow the changes have broken the original `.arg span` class definition I had, and it doesn't seem to help to change it to `.arg > span` (as I have done) or to change the left `margin` from 74 to 144. You can see the resulting problem in the browser-rendered page by searching for "Sum of your First Argument" or just going down to 'pages' 408–10 by consulting the page numbers in the left-hand margin.

In short, `.arg > span` doesn't work, specifically `margin: 1 0 0 74;` doesn't seem to do anything, and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need units on nonzero values.

```
margin: 1px 0 0 74px;
```

`0` is the only value for which units are not required. Regardless of the unit (assuming units of finite size, anyway), zero is always zero.

Comment: Boy, do I feel dumb. You're a gentleman and a scholar, and I'll accept this answer ASAP.

Comment: There are exceptions of the rule "0 is the only value for which units not required". Angles, times and frequencies require unit designators in all cases.